# Why is the Brunhilde hat restricted to non-SO?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I remember the identical Running Ragged hat from last year. However, that hat excluded Stack Overflow for the specific reason of balancing the 2 hats that were *exclusive* to Stack Overflow, neither of which I see in the list this year. (Or are those secret hats now?)

So what gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earning reputation and getting badges is easier on Stack Overflow due to the sheer amount of active users in there.

Writing a decent and good answer on SO would likely get a quick 10 upvotes, while on smaller sites it might take long days to reach same amount of votes.

So having "non-SO hats" is very fair in my opinion, and let users who don't use Stack Overflow get hats as well.

Comment: Funnily enough, I find it harder to earn rep on SO due to questions getting lost in the sheer volume of posts.